# How to get multiple lambdas in one cloudwatch graph using aws-cdk for python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I am using python in aws-cdk to create some graphs, alerts, sns topics etc.

My goal is to create a graph that takes a lambda metric for example "Errors" from all lambdas existing in some aws console space

So far I've found examples defining a single lambda from a local path as function, like:

```
lambdaFunction = _lambda.Function(
        self,
        id='someLambda',
        runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
        'handler='medium.handler',
        code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(path='src'),
        )
```

My question is: Is it possible to define all lambdas from aws console to later put them in a graph? Is something like this possible?

```
errors_widget = aws_cloudwatch.GraphWidget(title= "Errors",
    left=[all_lambdas_function.metric_errors()],
    width=24)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reference existing AWS resources, such as lambdas defined in the console, in your CDK app.

First, get a CDK reference to your lambda with the from the `from_function_arn` [classmethod on Lambda.Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/Function.html?highlight=from_function_arn#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function.from_function_arn).  You give it the function ARN and it returns an `IFunction` type.

```py
arn = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:<MYACCOUNT>:function:my-existing-great-function"
my_existing_lambda: IFunction = _lambda.Function.from_function_arn(self, "ExistingLambdaFunction", arn)
```

From then on, you can call [IFunction's methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/IFunction.html) to add things like `metric_errors` on `my_existing_lambda`.